# Remove file path from CURL file upload request

Tags: php, curl

I am using CURL to POST upload files on a web-service. Server returns a XML with file name with which it puts file in a storage DB for further processing. Simplified code below:

```
$post['uploadfile'] = new CurlFile('src/files/file.png', 'image/png');

$ch = curl_init($target_url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Server side code is unavailable for me, and the problem is that server returns me a path for the uploaded file like this:

```
src_files_file.png
```

I guess i have missed a field in request, that holds clear name for file. How could it be resolved to

```
file.png
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I not sure that I fully understand your question, but I think you search third parameter in `CurlFile` constructor:

```
$post['uploadfile'] = new CurlFile('src/files/file.png', 'image/png', 'file.png');
```